# The stack in assembly

Tags: assembly, stack

I am using the intel syntax on linux, and I'm looking at this code, why does it work?

```
.global asm2

asm2:                               
    push    ebp                     
    mov     ebp,esp                 
    sub     esp,0x10                
    mov     eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc] ???? 
    mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],eax 
    ;  0x14  
    ;  0x0f 
    ;  0x0c  
    ;  0x08  
    ;  0x04
    ;  0x00 - ret_val
    ;  -0x04_-0x0c = ebp
```

How does the stack place `eax` in the stack? Won't it ram over the return address? (I'm talking about the line `mov eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]`

Comment: The return address is at `ebp+4` not `ebp+0xc`. In any case that's a read not a write. It's loading an argument and storing it as a local variable (assuming cdecl calling convention).

Comment: that's intel syntax, in intel syntax it's `mov source, dest`, and isn't the return address spread on 4 bytes? can it fit in 1 or 2 bytes?

Comment: And `eax` is `dest` in the line you're curious about.

Comment: @tkausl but I'm using intel syntax

Comment: Yes, and in intel syntax, the line `mov     eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]` copies `DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]` to `eax`.

Comment: Why did you edit your previous comment? Intel syntax uses its first argument as `dest`, you had it correct until your edited the comment. Also, the line _does_ move 4 bytes, as the arguments are a 4-byte register and a 4-byte memory region (`DWORD PTR`)

Comment: thought it was the opposite, guess I confused it with AT&T syntax?

Comment: @help_in_asm AT&T syntax is `opcode source, dest` while Intel syntax is `opcode dest, source`.  You got a bit confused I think.